# Is MP3 decoding of JavaScript AudioContext and SoX different?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, sox, audiocontext

I use AudioNode to decode my MP3 files on my webpage.
The tool I am using is [Plucked](https://github.com/plucked/html5-audio-editor). I also edit my MP3 files with SoX.

Because the results are different, I did a test with an MP3 file ([xx.mp3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/za3hhh8479o9erk/xx.mp3?dl=0)). I got the information of xx.mp3 with `Plucked`( AudioNode.AudioContext.decodeAudioData() ):

```
Samples: 46731
Length(seconds): 1.0596598386764526
```

Then I run `sox xx.mp3 -n stat`:

```
Samples: 49536
Length(seconds): 1.123265
```

Both the two results of Sample Rate is: 44100

Why the results are different?

I use the following example to test again: https://github.com/mdn/decode-audio-data

The result of sample number is 46731 again.

And I test with other tool, such as Audacity, the number is 49536.

So I think there is something wrong with JavaScript `AudioContext decodeAudioData()`

Update:

The results in different browsers are:

Safari(OS X):`46731`

Chrome(OS X):`46731`

Firefox(OS X):`47855`

Chrome(Win7):`50863`

Safari(iOS 9):`46731`

I use [web-audio-api](https://github.com/sebpiq/node-web-audio-api) in Node.js to try again.

The result of `AudioNode.AudioContext.decodeAudioData()` is `49536`.

I really don't know why...

Comment: _Very_ late with this answer I know, but it's because FFMPEG, used by some browsers under the hood, removes padded silence from the start. Related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=591960